# How to create single API for getallUsers and getUser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to create a single API to get all users and a single user. How can I create an API for this?

Currently, I had APIs like this.

To get All Users:

```
router.get(`/`, async (req, res) =>{
    const userList = await User.find().select('-password')
    if(!userList) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false})
    } 
    res.send(userList);
})
```

To get single User:

```
router.get('/:id' , async (req,res) =>{
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select('-password')
    if(!user){
        res.status(500).json({message: 'The User with give id is not found'})
    }
    res.status(200).send(user)
})
```

Now my requirement is that have to create a single API for above both APIs.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say clients that they should send *all* as id if they require all the users.

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.id === "all") {
    const userList = await User.find().select("-password");
    if (!userList) {
      res.status(500).json({ success: false });
    }
    res.send(userList);
  } else {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select("-password");
    if (!user) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "The User with give id is not found" });
    }
    res.status(200).send(user);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a router

```
let router = express.Router();
  

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("Specific User Router Working");

    res.end();
});
 

router.get('/all', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("All User Router Working");

    res.end();
});
 
app.use('/user',router);
```

Comment: I am doing like above only. but in one API only i have to do both functionalities.

Comment: My understanding of your words is that I want you to do two things in a root if you use parameters like this and create a variable that this endpoint wants all users or not.